# Powershell one-liner to print process properties

Tags: string, powershell, object, unix, text

I'm trying to teach myself my Powershell (5.1) and said

`PS > Get-Process | Export-CSV process.csv`

As an exercise, I would like extract the second line of process.csv, print all the properties in the 2nd line of process.csv on separate lines an automatically number them using a PS one-liner.

In *nix, I would say something like

`head -2 process.csv | tail -1 | tr "," "\n" | nl`

But I'm having a hard time replicating this kind of one-liner in PS.  Maybe I'm not supposed to try in the first place.  In any event, below is how far I've gotten:

`` (get-content process.csv -TotalCount 2 | select -Index 1).Replace(",", "`r`n") ``

It kinda works, and outputs this

"Name"
"SI"
"Handles"...

which is not exaclty what I'm looking for.  PS says the output is one big string object, not separate lines.  So, I'm assuming that the multiple lines contained in the one big object/string need to be piped as single objects to '''foreach''' , but I can't figure out how to do it.  In any event, I want the output to look like this...

1. Name
2. SI
3. Handles...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance! Very Respectully.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one liner in power shell for the results:

```
(ps)[1] | select *
```

Now for your steps:Just get 10..

```
(ps)[0..9] | select * | export-csv -path "c:\temp\ps_$(Get-Date -f "mmddyyy").csv" -NoTypeInformation -force

$lineprops = (import-csv -path "c:\temp\ps_$(Get-Date -f "mmddyyy").csv")[1]
```

This is a ps object so you can select properties etc.

```
$lineprops.name

$lineprops | select name, id , CPU
```

want to index it use array for some more fun

```
$arrayofvalues = ($lineprops.PSObject.Properties).value 

$arrayofvalues[0,2,2,6+10..13+15] 

[array]::IndexOf($arrayofvalues,$arrayofvalues[10]) # kinda redundant by true
```

here is the indexed objects

```
$indexed=@()
$psnow=(ps)[0..9]
foreach($i in $psnow )
{ 
    $indexed += [pscustomobject]@{ Name=$i.name; ID=$i.id; index = [array]::IndexOf($psnow,$i)}
}
$indexed
```

## Compact this all down to one line

```
((ipcsv -path c:\file.csv)[1].PSObject.Properties).value  | %{$i++;[pscustomobject]@{ Value=$_; Index = $i}}
```

you could add this to an array list to speed it up

Comment: Hi HappyBob, 
Thank you for the speedy reply.  Not exaclty a one-line solution, but you've given me some good ideas.  Thank you.

Comment: Was not quite clear what you were asking a one liner to export the second object in process to a .csv and then re-import them in the same line?  so I provided a few different ways to get similar results .   (ps)[1] | select *  is the one-liner for the second-object.

Comment: you're right. My post should have been clear, and I edited it for clarity.  Thanks for your responses.  I'm definitely learning more about Powershell from your code.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to HappyBob, research, and trial and error, I came up with the following Powershell one-liner:

`$a = (gc process.csv -Tot 2)[1]; $i=1; ("$a".Replace('"','')).Split(',') | %($_) {"$i"+".  "+"$_"; $i++}`

which outputs

1. Name
2. SI
3. Handles